# Oracle JDBC insertion through stored procedure using Java

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to insert a record in Oracle 11g using Java. I'm still learning Java.

I've to call stored procedure to insert a record. My primary key in users table is user_id. I also have a sequence incremented by 2 on user_id

Now, while setting the input params in Java, what do I need to pass in user_id? Also, what would be the type in case of date param:

```
Users:user_id number (primary key), email varchar, created_date Date
```

I've below java code:

```
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");          
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@101.12.11.11:1521:demo", "demo_app", "demo");

        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{exec demo.my_pkg.insert_users(?,?,?)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.setInt(1, ?????);

        cs.execute();
```

Do I need to set user_id here? If yes, what should I set it to, since its a sequence?
What about date field & email field?

Do I need registerOutParameter here? If so, why?

And finally, how will I get the confirmation that the insertion is successful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do I need to set user_id here?
   RE: You can get a sequence value before you set it:

   select sequence_name.nextval from dual
2. Do I need registerOutParameter here? If so, why?
   RE: If you want to get a return value, you can registerOutParameter, if not, forget it.
3. how will I get the confirmation that the insertion is successful?
   RE: You can get result from a out parameter or a procedure's return value

Comment: Can I pass sequence directly as CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{exec demo.my_pkg.insert_users(seq_users.nextval,?,?)}");

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a trigger/calculation of user_id in stored procedure, than, yes, you need to pass user_id from Java code (get next sequence value in Java, and pass it to your stored function).
You need to register out parameter if your function returns value.
Confirmation depends on implementation. For example, if your function returns was user inserted or not, just check return value.

Comment: What if I've a trigger for sequence? What do I need to pass in the param?

Comment: In this case user_id is generated inside you database and you should not pass it from java. And if you have a trigger, why do you have user_id parameter in stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Do I need registerOutParameter here? If so, why?

yes you need to registerOutParameter if your stored procedure returns any value(i.e it is a function)

For setting date field use the java.sql.Date class as Type.